# Procedure too large VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I finally finished my first code which is supposed to extract information from a selected document into a template. its a really large template and therefore I have massive amount of lines. I really hoped you could help me!

```
  Sub Test2()
    ' Test2 Macro

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = ""

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .Title = "Select File"
        .Filters.Add "Excel File", "*.xls?"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show Then
            FileName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If Len(FileName) < 4 Then Exit Sub 'No file selected

    Dim TempWorkbook As Workbook, CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet 'Store the ActiveSheet, it will change
    Set TempWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    CurrentSheet.Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)


   CurrentSheet.Range("A134").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(214, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A135").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(214, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A136").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(214, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
    CurrentSheet.Range("A137").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(214, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)

    TempWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set TempWorkbook = Nothing
    Set CurrentSheet = Nothing

    End Sub
```

The above is the first and last section of the code. Ive been trying to split it up in multiple procedures, but that did not go well. I hoped someone could help with splitting it up?

Best regards
Christian

Comment: Break your code into smaller subroutines. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/procedure-too-large)

Comment: You need to DRY out your code (DRY = [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)). There is no reason to have large number of lines which essentially do the same thing but to different cells. Why not use loops? Your sentence "its a really large template and therefore I have massive amount of lines" doesn't really make sense. Small code can operate on large spreadsheets.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am new to VBA but Loop sounds very good. Can you give an example with my code of how it would look like?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if your procedure has more than a dozen lines, it's very likely doing too many things.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - oops, I'd have to re-write several of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things you can do in your code:

1) Use the fact that formulas can be set for ranges and not just individual cells:

The four lines

```
CurrentSheet.Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
CurrentSheet.Range("A9").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
CurrentSheet.Range("A10").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
CurrentSheet.Range("A11").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
```

is equivalent to the single line:

```
CurrentSheet.Range("A8:A11").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(16, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
```

2) Use a loop. I don't quite see the logic of what you are doing, but something along the lines of the following might work:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 8 To 128 Step 6
    CurrentSheet.Range(CurrentSheet.Cells(i,1),CurrentSheet.Cells(i+5,1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & TempWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL FORM").Cells(???, 3).Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
Next i
```

Where the step size and `???` is computed from your index according to the logic of your problem. Such loops can be tricky to set up just right, but are definitely worth it.